# cloud converter app error message

Tags: sales-cloud

Cloud Converter Cannot Continue
Message: Couldn't execute metadata binding create. (UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Async job could not be executed).

Trying to upload a new Object using excel worksheet into salesforce using Cloud Converter and this is the error. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the Cloud Converter app. Have you tried contacting the app vendor?

Answer (score 1):

it is issue due to summer 14 version (API 31) . you can only create 6 bundle of metadata at a time.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000AcQvIAK

Comment: Has this been fixed yet to allow more than 6 fields created at a time???

Comment: I believe it is not fixed yet.